# deleting multiple duplicate rows from a database even if some of the columns may be NULL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I inherited a database that contains a table with a crazy amount of duplicates due to a lack of a unique primary key.  Sadly, before I can add a primary key, I need to delete all the dupes except 1.

So I found A LOT of wonderful answers on here and followed all the advice I read.

Here is the query I ended up with:

```
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY storyId, storyDescription, genreId, authorId, submissionDate, submittedBy, submissionUrl 
                                       ORDER BY ( SELECT 0)) RN
         FROM   storyList)
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE  RN > 1;
```

It did delete 90% of the duplicate entries.  However it won't delete rows that contain NULL values in some of the columns.

Happily I searched through the other answers and comments for similar questions but couldn't find any that deal with potential NULL values.

Is there such a way to delete the remaining duplicate entries even though some of their columns may contain a NULL value?

Thank you

Comment: Can you insert the rows you want to keep into a temporary table, truncate storyList, and then re-insert the rows from your temporary table?

Comment: Is there _always_ one row that has no nulls? If not, which partial row is the "original" that others duplicate? Or do you want to somehow coalesce values to fill in missing values?

Comment: @HABO storyId doesn't have any rows that are null.  The rows are duplicates, including nulls.  For example there could be 3 rows that are exactly, `123, 'an awesome story', 3, 45, NULL, NULL, 'google.com'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete those separately:

```
delete from storylist
    where storyId is null or storyDescription is null  or genreId is null or . . .
```

However, that seems rather strange.  Why isn't `storyid` the candidate primary key?  Are you intending to use all the columns?

EDIT:

I think you want to keep `storyid` as the primary and prioritize non-null values in the other columns.  If so:

```
WITH cte as (
      SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY storyId 
                                    ORDER BY ( (CASE WHEN storyDescription IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
                                               (CASE WHEN genreId IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
                                               . . .
                                             ) DESC
                          ) as seqnum
      FROM storyList
     )
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE seqnum > 1;
```

Comment: Hi!  thank you! I want to make storyId the primary key.  It is never null in any of the rows for that table.  But sometimes these columns do show me null: submissionDate, submittedBy, submissionUrl.  When one of or more of those are NULL, it doesn't delete them.  thank you!

Comment: Hi I tried your query above but it didn't work.  It said 0 rows affected.  An example of a duplicate row that it didn't work on is this: `storyId  storyDescription genreId authorId  submissionDate submittedBy submissionUrl
'abceur123' 'A test of Will' 1 NULL NULL NULL NULL`

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell . . . The `partition by` on the second query now only has `storyid`.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long to be a comment. So it goes.

If I understand correctly, the following code demonstrates what you are trying to do. Am I still not getting it or could you post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the issue? (Perhaps a [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/).)

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Samples as Table ( SampleId Int Identity, SomeString VarChar(16), SomeInt Int );
insert into @Samples ( SomeString, SomeInt ) values
  ( 'foo', 3 ), ( 'foo', 9 ), ( 'foo', null ), ( 'foo', 9 ), ( 'foo', null ),
  ( 'bar', 6 ), ( 'bar', 6 ), ( 'bar', null ), ( 'bar', 6 ), ( 'bar', null ),
  ( null, null ), ( null, 6 ), ( null, null ), ( null, 6 ), ( null, null );
select SampleId, SomeString, SomeInt
  from @Samples
  order by SampleId;

-- Get row numbers just to show they are calculated correctly.
select SampleId, SomeString, SomeInt,
  Row_Number() over ( partition by SomeString, SomeInt order by SampleId ) as RN
  from @Samples
  order by SomeString, SomeInt, RN;

-- Delete duplicates.
with NumberedRows as (
  select -- SampleId, SomeString, SomeInt,
    Row_Number() over ( partition by SomeString, SomeInt order by SampleId ) as RN
    from @Samples )
  delete from NumberedRows
    where RN > 1;
  
-- Display the remainder.
select SampleId, SomeString, SomeInt
  from @Samples
  order by SampleId;
```

Comment: wow that worked for 99%. Now I just have like 125 dupes of 2 left that look like this(an example) and I'm not sure why the above solution didn't work. `DCC88  Doom Woods  1 NULL NULL NULL NULL`  they are all the same pattern as above.  Two identical rows with the same storyId, same storyDescription, a categoryId of 1, and then NULLS for the rest.

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell Do the problem rows get assigned correct row numbers, but fail to `delete`? Are any of the null columns an unusual data type? (Not that I know why that would matter.)